# How to operate 1602 LCD on 3.3V

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, 3.3v, character-lcd

I wonder if its possible to run a common 16x2 LCD with 3.3v power supply. Its datasheet shows supply voltage = 5V. Are there any 3.3V variants of 16x2 LCD modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be possible to use it at 3.3v. Usually the chip itself will work at 3.3v but the liquid crystals in the LCD glass may needs higher voltages. It might be possible to give negative contrast voltages to drive the glass better, but the glass supply voltage biasing may not be optimal. There is no module type code or a link to a datasheet so it is not known if using it with 3.3v is possible at all. There are 3.3v modules which generate negative voltages onboard so the can be used just as easily as 5v modules.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few character mode displays that are available for operation at 3.3V. The ones that I have encountered are OLED modules so you may want to investigate that type including the NewHaven brand.

Almost all other displays that I have found that operate at 3.3V are going to be graphic type displays. These take a bit more software to get them going but the flexibility is often well worth the effort in terms of font selection and ability to support graphics operations. You can find ready made libraries of code for graphic LCDs in support of Arduino's and rPi's. If you want something a little bit more oriented to a "build my own" solution you can find some useful information on graphic LCDs (GLCD) at my web site. Thread through my SE profile to find that.